# JQuery Remove last element, multi calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have the following JQuery code that will remove the last element in a container. THe problem is that my remove is animated, and this method will for example be called 10 times in a row, then will only 2 or 3 elements be remove, because the next wall will catch the object that is already being removed, but is currently fading out.

```
        var last = self.options.FollowsContainer.children().last();
        self.usersInFollowsList--;
        if (last != null) {
            last.fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
```

I have tryed the following, but it did not work

```
    var last = self.options.FollowsContainer.find(":not(.removing):last");
    self.usersInFollowsList--;
    if (last != null) {
        last.addClass("removing");
        last.fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
```

Comment: `var last = self.options.FollowsContainer.children(':not(:animated)').last();`

Comment: Not getting understand

Comment: @adeneo you solution worked, can you add an anwser so i can accept it?

Comment: Of course it did, I see someone already posted it, so that's fine, just happy to help.

Comment: @smerny - Got that rigth, darn it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the jQuery selector `:animated`

```
self.options.FollowsContainer.children(":not(:animated):last").fadeOut(function () {
    this.remove();
});
```

It gets the last not animated child and fade it out

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, modified to easily fit in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb9qA/

```
var numBeingRemoved = 0;
$("#remove").on("click", function () {
    numBeingRemoved++;
    $("#foos").children(":nth-last-child(" + numBeingRemoved + ")").fadeOut(function () {
        this.remove();
        numBeingRemoved--;
    });
});
```